# Derivative of a scalar given by a function times its hessian

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Is there any way of doing the below but by avoiding $d^3f\over dx^3$?

If for a row vector $x$ e.g. size (3x1):

$f=f(x)=scalar$

$g={df\over dx}$ i.e. the gradient

$H={d^2f\over dx^2}$ i.e. the Hessian

$M=fH$

Then the derivate of $M$ w.r.t. $x$ is given by

$$dM={dM\over df}df+{dM\over dH}dH$$
$$dM={H}df+{f}dH$$
$$dM={H}(gdx)+{f}{dH\over dx}dx$$
$${dM\over dx}=Hg+{f}{dH\over dx}$$
$${dM\over dx}=Hg+{f}{df^3\over dx^3}$$

Comment: $\frac{dM}{dx}$ is a 3rd order tensor, which is awkward to deal with in matrix notation. What are you going to do with it? I assume the reason you'd like to avoid $\frac{df^3}{dx^3}$ is because it is also an awkward 3rd order tensor.

If you really need it you'll have to learn to work with it. Perhaps index notation would be better suited to your problem.

Comment: Also the way you've written the term $(Hg)$ is misleading. It's *also* a 3rd order tensor. The product between the two is not the standard matrix-vector product, or even a Kronecker product, but a **tensor** product. So a better notation would be something like $(H\star g)$

Comment: Thanks. I will deal with the 3rd order tensor. ${dM}\over dx$ was part of the calculation of a tangent so that I could use the Newton-Raphson Method.